# Java split string at "," and end of line

Tags: java, string, split

I have some data that looks like this:

```
2000-01-05,5.15,5.25,5.05,5.18,42500,5.03
2000-01-04,5.86,5.94,4.99,5.38,56700,5.23
2000-01-03,5.86,5.92,5.59,5.80,84600,5.64
```

Now I do want to split the string at the "," and at the end of the line. I tried it like this:

```
String[] results = file.split(",");
```

This works fine, but when I try this:

```
String[] results = file.split(",||\\n+");
```

The whole thing gets messed up, I hope you can help :)

Comment: "The whole thing gets messed up" Well, what does it do? Does it do nothing? Make an error? Crash your computer? Make flying monkeys fall from the sky? Give you free waffles? Please clarify. (-1)

Comment: It is just giving us some headache, nothing special.

Comment: How about reading the file line by line using a bufferedreader, then splitting the lines on ,

Comment: The double pipe (`a||b`) will match `a` or `b` or an empty string, the empty string being between every character and the next.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a better way:

```
String[] results = a.split(",|"+System.getProperty("line.separator")+"+");
```

Because the line separator changes between OS..

Comment: This will result in `",|\n+"` or `",|\r\n+"`, not the escaped `",|\\n+"` or `",|\\r\\n+"`.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
String[] results = file.split(",|\\n+");
```